# Completing a proof under binomial expansion

Tags: discrete-mathematics, fractions, binomial-theorem

Recently my discrete mathematics lecturer gave the following problem under the topic of binomial expansion:

If x is nearly equal to unity (1), prove that:
$$\frac {mx^n - nx^m}{x^n - x^m} = \frac 1{1-x}$$

What I've so far determined that $\vert x \vert < 1$ since the denominator is a binomial:

$$x^{-n}(1-x^{m-n})^{-1}$$

So far my expression is in the following form:

$$ \frac {m-nx^{m-n}}{1-x^{m-n}} $$

From here I think $m-n = 1$ and I've tried to prove using the fact that

$$\lim_{a \to \infty} x^a = 0, \space where \space \vert x \vert < 1$$
$$x^n > x^m, \space where \space m > n$$

I don't know if this is the correct way to prove that the expression equals $$\frac 1{1-x}$$
Thanks in advance and have a great day.

Comment: Use Taylor series around $x=1$ for numerator and denominator and long division

Comment: If x is nearly equal to unity (1), prove that:  
$\frac {mx^n - nx^m}{x^n - x^m} = \frac 1{1-x}$: This is not a valid Mathematical statement.

Comment: @geetha290krm Could you elaborate?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I haven't learnt Taylor series yet, so I'm not sure if that approach is supposed to be used, but I'll try read on it and see if it works. But in essence I have to get the Taylor series of the numerator and denominator separately and long divide them. Isn't a Taylor series also infinite, how far to the $n^{\text th}$ term am I supposed to expand to?

Comment: @BrickSigma. Let $x=1+t$ and use the binomial expansion. For example $$(1+t)^n=1+n t+\frac{1}{2} (n-1) n t^2$$ could be sufficient.